# executing exec('wmic process call create notepad') causing McAfee to quarantine cmd.exe

Tags: php, wmic, mcafee

In windows command line prompt the command `wmic process call create notepad` will open notepad and also report the process Id. This command work fine on my computer.

However, running this command via php exec() function causing McAffe to recognize it as a virus threat TIE/Suspect!.

o.php file:

```
 <?php
    exec("wmic process call create notepad");
```

Immediately after running `php o.php` C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe is moved to Quarantine by McAfee

At this point I'm sure this is false-positive detection

This is not related to notepad because with any other command I have the same effect

The command `exec("notepad");` works fine

Because of that problem my php project is not working when antivirus is turned on
Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Just turn your antivirus off or change it !